# BinaryFormatter.Serialize adding 28 to byte array length

Tags: .net, arrays, serialization, f#, stream

I have the following code snippet which receives a message on a `TcpClient` network stream, which may contain some content under the form of an `obj` type, and tries to serialize it to a byte array:

```
let readStreamToFile (client:TcpClient) outputPath =
    let formatter = new BinaryFormatter()

    try
        let message = (formatter.Deserialize (client.GetStream ())) :?> Message
        match message.Type with
        | FileTransfer ->
            match message.Content with
            | Some content ->
                let bytesContent = 
                    use mStream = new MemoryStream()
                    formatter.Serialize (mStream, content)
                    mStream.ToArray ()

                File.WriteAllBytes (outputPath, bytesContent)
            | None ->
                failwith "There was no content in the FileSync message!!!"
        | _ ->
            ()
    with
    | :? InvalidCastException as ex ->
        failwith "Message format unknown!!!"
```

Unfortunately, when I debug this code, I can see that the content received is good, and has a length of 46, but the call to `mStream.ToArray ()` after `formatter.Serialize (mStream, content)` has a length of 74. That is, it adds 28 item **before** the actual array of length 46. Those 28 items are not empty either, some contain values.

Is this normal? How can I make it that `bytesContent` always is the same as my `obj` `content`?

Comment: If you just want the bytes, why call `formatter.Serialize`, why not just grab the bytes?

Comment: A BinaryFormatter encodes both the object's type info and value on serialization.  The type info is needed to reconstruct the object on deserialization.

Comment: @TnTinMn beat me to it by a minute. The extra 28 bytes are the type info, in some format that BinaryFormatter understands -- so that when it deserializes the data, it will be able to produce an object of the correct type.

Comment: As aforementioned comments state, this is doing exactly what you're telling it to do.  The bigger question is what you're wanting and why.

Comment: If @TnTinMn want to add that as an answer, I will gladly accept it. I am guessing this is caused by me not calling Deserialize before Serialize.

Comment: @Choub890, I'll gladly add it as an answer, but I am concerned that you still concerned that your code may not be giving you what you expect. You want to write `content` to a file; what data type is `content`?  Is it a `String`?

Comment: @TnTinMn I was over complicating my life while defining my network communications, content is a `byte[]` so there is actually no need to deserialize/serialize it, I can just send it as a `byte[]` and then just call `File.WriteAllBytes`. The only thing I need to serialize/deserialize is my Message type :)

Comment: Ok, I'll remove my series of questions from the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A BinaryFormatter encodes both the object's type info and value on serialization. The type info is needed to reconstruct the object on deserialization.  The extra bytes are the type information.